# Grails wrong evaluation of expression

Tags: grails, groovy

I wrote a function in my service class where I evaluate a passed parameters from controller but Grails is returning wrong evaluation results.

```
 def list(String q,String qval,String srt,String ord){
 log.debug("q==="+q)
 log.debug("qval==="+qval)
 log.debug("srt==="+srt)
 log.debug("order==="+ord)
```

all these debug statements print null as expected. Now

```
boolean qvalbool=qval?.trim()
log.debug("qvalbool===>>"+qvalbool) prints true!!!

!StringUtils.isEmpty(q) && !StringUtils.isEmpty(qval) returns true!!
```

both statements should return false while they are returning true what is going on with this? any ideas?

I'm using grails 2.4.2

Comment: maybe the input are "null" as String? that's why you see null when you are printing them?

Comment: The input is null but the condition result should be false while it shows true

Comment: Run debugger and check what the exact value is. As @evanwong mentioned - you might getting `"null"` and not `null`, that's why other conditions are evaluated to `true`. If you want to println exact data type, try `log.debug(q?.dump())` and see if you get `null` or `<String@23e... value=null>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Evan Wong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/973339/evanwong)'s comment is very likely correct that you're seeing a string containing the word null.

Often when Groovy prints out values it's not apparent what their type is.

```
groovy:000> null
===> null
groovy:000> 'null'
===> null
```

Also in Groovy the expression `null + ''` evaluates to the String `'null'`.

That would be an easy way to change the value of this parameter so it contains the string 'null'.

Comment: Thanks this was the problem I was adding '' to null which evaluates to 'null'.